# General Question as best practice to collect data from extended events

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, extended-events

Hope ya all doing good and safe:-

I am collecting query level metrics from extended events using below events for -

```
SP statement completed
SQL Statement completed
SQL Batch Completed
RPC Completed
```

I have seen sometimes similar queries collecting in many events which look similar. I am not able to understand why exactly? Can someone explain exactly whats the major difference between these 4 events. This is just for my dev servers as a test to see what i am collecting.Is there an event for one fit all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain exactly what's the major difference between these 4 events

```
SQL Batch Completed
RPC Completed
```

Clients submit batches of SQL Statements using a "SQL Batch" or an "RPC". These events track those client requests.  SQL Batches can also be sumbitted by `sp_executesql` or `exec (@sql)` from other batches or a stored procedure.

```
SQL Statement completed
```

Each SQL Batch will contain zero or more "SQL Statements".  This event tracks the execution of those statements.

```
SP statement completed
```

A SQL Statement or an RPC can invoke a Stored Procedure which in turn has multiple statements inside it.  When a stored procedure runs you get a "SP Statement Completed" event for each statement in the stored proedure.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But i am more curious for how i can avoid duplicate calls in those 4 events as sometime same queries seems to be getting captured from all. it might be not worth collecting so many duplicate calls

Comment: @BeginnerDBA, if you are interested in calls rather than individual statements, just capture sql_batch_completed and rpc_completed.The others provide statement level detail.